# How to make minor mode keybindings for C-c prefix?

Tags: keymap, minor-mode

I am trying to define a minor mode that makes 2 keybindings. This is code i am defining it with:

```
(define-minor-mode parinfer-mode
  "Uses Parinfer to Format lispy code"
  :lighter " parinfer"
  :keymap '(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
             (define-key map (kbd "C-c t") 'parinfer-mode--toggle)
             (define-key map (kbd "C-c r") 'parinfer-mode--refresh)
             map)
  (if parinfer-mode
      (parinfer-mode--refresh)))
```

However, when i later eval `parinfer-mode`, those bindings remain undefined, and value of `parinfer-mode-map` is:

```
 (67 keymap
     (45 keymap
         (99 keymap
             (32 keymap
                 (114 . parinfer)
                 (116 . parinfer-mode--toggle))))))
```

What should i change to set keymap the way i want?

P.S. I am not interested in defining mode separately, but in understanding what goes wrong in using an approach described in documentation.

Comment: The `:keymap` argument is a pain to use correctly.  Better stay away from it and just use `(defvar parinfer-mode-map (let ... map))` instead (placed before the `define-minor-mode`).